# How to get Python List from QVariant

Tags: python, list, qt, pyqt, qvariant

If `Qt.UserRole` the model's `headerData()` returns a Python list variable:

```
if role==Qt.UserRole:
    return QVariant(['one','two','three'])
```

Instead of a regular Python list a function that calls with:

```
returnedValue = myModel(index.column(), Qt.Horizontal, Qt.UserRole)
```

gets a `QVariant` object:

```
<PyQt4.QtCore.QVariant object at 0x10d3b67c0>
```

An attempt to convert the returned `QVariant` object to Python using:

```
pythonList=returnedValue.toPyObject()
```

didn't work. I have tried to do:

for each in returnedValue.toList():
    print each

But that still prints out some QVariants. What method should be used to convert QVariant to Python list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

QVariant is a general container for almost all kinds of built-in types, so in order to cast QVariant data back, you need to know what kind of data it is stored.

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QVariant

a = QVariant(['one', 'two', 'three'])

aList = [unicode(i.toString()) for i in a.toList()]
print aList
```

output is as :

`[u'one', u'two', u'three']`